# fireEditingStopped() method of TreeCellEditor

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i have a sample code from some swing tutorial. in the code we add a JTree to a panel, and then we customize rendering and editing the tree. we want for leafs of tree to be JCheckBoxes, so user can check or uncheck each one.

as a custom TreeCellEditor, i create a class that implements TreeCellEditor and also extends AbstractCellEditor, so in my class i override just these tree methods:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e)
public Object getCellEditorValue()
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, boolean arg4, int arg5)
```

and in the last class, it check if user try to edit a leaf, it invokes the fireEditingStopped() method in the ItemListener of the checkbox(leafs are rendered as checkboxes). it's wierd! we still don't edit anything and fire editing stopped! so what exactly does this method?

footnote: we setUserObject of each leaf to an instance of ServerInfo class, where has 3 fields: name, id, and checked.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;


public class Main extends JFrame{
    private MPanel mPanel;

    public Main() {
        mPanel = new MPanel();
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(mPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
class MPanel extends JPanel{
    private JTree serverTree;
    public MPanel() {
        serverTree = new JTree(createTree());
        serverTree.setCellRenderer(new ServerTreeCellRenderer());
        serverTree.setCellEditor(new ServerTreeCellEditor());
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(serverTree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode createTree() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Servers");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode branch1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("USA");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode server1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ServerInfo("New York",1,true));

        branch1.add(server1);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode branch2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("UK");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode server4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ServerInfo("London", 4, false));
        branch2.add(server4);

        top.add(branch1);
        top.add(branch2);

        return top;
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////
class ServerInfo{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private boolean selected;
    public ServerInfo(String name, int id, boolean selected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.selected=selected;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return selected;
    }
    public void setChecked(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name + "-->" + selected;
    }
}
////////////////////////////////
class ServerTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private JCheckBox leafRenderer;
    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafNode;

    public ServerTreeCellRenderer() {
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object node, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode theNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)node;

        if(leaf) {
            ServerInfo info = (ServerInfo)theNode.getUserObject();
            leafRenderer = new JCheckBox(info.getName());
            leafRenderer.setSelected(info.isChecked());
            return leafRenderer;
        }else {
            nonLeafNode = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
            //nonLeafNode.setClosedIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/earthplus.gif")));
            //nonLeafNode.setOpenIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/earth.gif")));
            return nonLeafNode.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, node, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        }
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////

class ServerTreeCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {
    private ServerTreeCellRenderer renderer;
    private ServerInfo info;
    private JCheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        info.setChecked(checkBox.isSelected());
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
        if(!(e instanceof MouseEvent)) return false;
        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent)e;
        JTree tree = (JTree)e.getSource();
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(),me.getY());
        if(path==null) return false;
        Object lastComp = path.getLastPathComponent();
        if(lastComp==null) return false;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode )lastComp;
        return node.isLeaf();
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf,int row) {

        Component comp = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,value,isSelected,expanded,leaf,row, true);
        if(leaf){
            DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode=(DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
            info = (ServerInfo)treeNode.getUserObject();
            checkBox = (JCheckBox)comp;
            ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
                    fireEditingStopped();
                    checkBox.removeItemListener(this);
                }
            };
            checkBox.addItemListener(itemListener);
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a minimal example reproducible?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo i do, but in my code i can't edit checkboxes, that i thought maybe its because of this fireEditingStopped method! anyway i put a runnable minimal code here, thank you

Comment: `ItemListener` will be called when the state of the `JCheckBox` changes (selected/deselected), personally, I'd use a `ActionListener`, less side effects, but that's me.  So, at the point that `itemStateChanged` is called, you have edited the state of the value, so calling stop editing is a valid task, this should force the `JTree` to call `getCellEditorValue` and modify the model state

Comment: Okay, you're going to hate you're self for this (I know it made me groan when I realised).  Add `serverTree.setEditable(true);` to you `MPanel` constructor.  This will make the table editable - but you'll get a `NullPointerException` in your editor, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to fix that ;)

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Thanks a lot